# Organizing Data in Excel Using VBA, Getting rid of blanks cells

Tags: excel, vba, datatables

The easiest way to understand what I need help with is viewing the images
The first is the original data and the second is what I want the data to be organized.
Original Data
[image: Original Data]

Data Organized
[image: Data Organized]

Is there a way of doing this through VBA efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### VBA Solution

This presumes you always have two rows as a separator.

```
Sub fixTwoColumns()
Const theRowDifference = 2

Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or whatever

Dim originalData As Range
    Set originalData = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0), ws.Range("A:B"))

Dim someValues()
    someValues = originalData.Value2

Dim c As Long, r As Long, m_Column As Long
    m_Column = UBound(someValues, 2)

For r = LBound(someValues) To UBound(someValues)
    For c = LBound(someValues, 2) To m_Column
        If c = LBound(someValues, 2) And Not (IsEmpty(someValues(r, c))) Then
        someValues(r, m_Column) = someValues(r + theRowDifference, m_Column)
           someValues(r + theRowDifference, m_Column) = Empty
           
        End If
    Next c
Next r

originalData.Value = someValues

    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=originalData.Columns(2) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange originalData
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

### Non VBA

This assumes you have spill-range functionality (all web-excel versions do).

Put this formula in cell D2: `=SORT(CHOOSE({1,2},FILTER(A:A,(ROW(A:A)>1)*(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))),FILTER(B:B,(ROW(B:B)>1)*(NOT(ISBLANK(B:B))))),2)`

The result will be your desired output.  [See example file.](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g6g88v5hd-9DlBxxRA?e=RligX6)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For older Excel versions.
In C2, refer to `=B4`. Then add a Filter and deselect blanks in column A.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove blanks column-by-column:

```vb
Dim arr, v, c As Long, r As Long, i As Long, rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:B1000") 'for example
arr = rng.Value
For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
    i = 0
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        v = arr(r, c)
        If Len(v) = 0 Then
            If i = 0 Then i = r
        Else
            If i > 0 Then
                arr(i, c) = v
                arr(r, c) = Empty
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next r
Next c
rng.Value = arr
```